# How to write a python code to print a result in excel sheet using .out file?

Tags: python, memcpy

I have  a bench-memcpy.out file. It contains input like below.
        
         `{
        "timing_type": "hp_timing",
        "functions": {
         "memset": {
         "bench-variant": "",
         "ifuncs": ["builtin_memset", "simple_memset", 
          "__memset_sse2_unaligned", 
                "__memset_sse2_unaligned_erms", "__memset_erms", 
                 "__memset_avx2_unaligned", "__memset_avx2_unaligned_erms"],
         "results": [
          {
         "length": 1,
          "alignment": 0,
          "char": -65,
           "timings": [101.812, 50.0625, 50.625, 46.6875, 60.1875, 55.125, 
           50.625]
           },
           {
           "length": 2,
           "alignment": 0,
           "char": -65,
            "timings": [61.3125, 45.5625, 47.25, 44.4375, 59.625, 50.0625, 
           48.9375]
            }]
            }
            }
          }`

 I have to print the timings  value in excel sheet.How can I do that?
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *easy* path is to use Excel's ability to open XML files.
Below is the code to produce timings.xml that Excel can open.

```
import json
#JSON loaded via a file (for instance)
f=open('bench-memcpy.out','r')
json_input = f.read()
f.close()
#defining XML header
output = '<?xml version="1.0"?><ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"><ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Timings"><ss:Table>'
#Load info as JSON data
json_data = json.loads(json_input)
#loop data
for r in range (0,len(json_data['functions']['memset']['results'])):
    output = output + '<ss:Row>'
    for t in range (0,len(json_data['functions']['memset']['results'][r]['timings'])):
        output += '<ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">' + str(json_data['functions']['memset']['results'][r]['timings'][t]) + '</ss:Data></ss:Cell>'
    output += '</ss:Row>'
output += '</ss:Table></ss:Worksheet></ss:Workbook>'
f=open('timings.xml','w')
f.write(output)
f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python pandas library for your desired operation. You can refer this link : [Kaggle flatten json](https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas)

Here, there is a nested json file. Author is flattening the file to extract his desired fields.